# NULLS being removed in unpivot

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I currently have the following code

```
with physician_diag as (

   SELECT baseentityid, eventdate,locationid,teamid,average_muac,child_age,child_gender,physician_diagnosis, dignosis_data
   FROM [VITAL_DWH].[vr].[event_physician_visit]   
UNPIVOT  
   (dignosis_data FOR physician_diagnosis  IN   
      (
     well_baby,
severe_pneumonia
)  
)

AS unpvt 
),

final as (
-- Final
select *, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY baseentityid ORDER BY eventdate) AS rn from (
select * from physician_diag  
 
 ) F
```

The problem is that NULLS are being removed, so I am missing out on some of the original rows. Any idea how to fix this? I have read that cross join lateral is a possible way, but I could not get a grip on how to implement that. Please help.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` removes nulls. You can instead use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to unpivot, this is in any case much more flexible.

```sql
with physician_diag as (
    SELECT
      baseentityid,
      eventdate,
      locationid,
      teamid,
      average_muac,
      child_age,
      child_gender,
      physician_diagnosis,
      dignosis_data
    FROM vr.event_physician_visit epv
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('well_baby', epv.well_baby),
        ('severe_pneumonia', epv.severe_pneumonia)
    ) v(physician_diagnosis, dignosis_data)
),
final as (
    select *,
      dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY baseentityid ORDER BY eventdate) AS rn
    from physician_diag  
)
.....
```

I note that you could possibly put the `DENSE_RANK` *before* unpivoting, which may allow it to hit an index. The results should be the same in this case.

```sql
with ranked as (
    select *,
      dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY epv.baseentityid ORDER BY epv.eventdate) AS rn
    from vr.event_physician_visit epv
),
final as (
    SELECT
      baseentityid,
      eventdate,
      locationid,
      teamid,
      average_muac,
      child_age,
      child_gender,
      physician_diagnosis,
      dignosis_data
    FROM ranked epv
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        ('well_baby', epv.well_baby),
        ('severe_pneumonia', epv.severe_pneumonia)
    ) v(physician_diagnosis, dignosis_data)
)
.....
```